# Is MyISAM storage engine preferable in Java Hibernate?

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, innodb, myisam

I want to make web application in java using **hibernate** and **spring**. 
So far i was testing my examples using innoDB storage engine.
I do not have complete knowledge about **hibernate** yet, but i have read in introduction of hibernate that it simplifies the complex join using ***foreign key***.

**EDIT:**

If i use MyIsam then i can't use ***foreign key*** in that. So i am asking that do hibernate allow similar operation without ***foreign key***.

Answer (score 2):

If you have the choice between the two, unless you need something really specific that is only in MyISAM (like [full-text indexing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Full_text_search#Indexing)), you should use InnoDB :

- *Data integrity* : InnoDB supports [foreign keys](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Foreign_key), [transactions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_transaction) and [rollback](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rollback_%28data_management%29), and is more resistant to table corruption than MyISAM.
- *Performance* : InnoDB supports row-level [locking](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Record_locking), compared to MyISAM table-level locking.
- *Future* : MyISAM is stagnant, and all the innovation is in InnoDB. If you plan to switch to [MariaDB](https://mariadb.org/) in the future, the default engine is [XtraDB](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/xtradb/), a fork of InnoDB. As of MySQL 5.5, [InnoDB is the default engine](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/innodb-default-se.html).

[Here](http://www.rackspace.com/knowledge_center/article/mysql-engines-myisam-vs-innodb) [are](http://tag1consulting.com/MySQL_Engines_MyISAM_vs_InnoDB) [some](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_MySQL_database_engines#Comparison_between_InnoDB_and_MyISAM) [links](http://linuxers.org/howto/myisam-or-innodb-mysql-engine) [comparing](http://phpdailycode.blogspot.com.au/p/what-is-difference-between-myisam-and.html) [the](http://runastartup.com/myisam-or-innodb-mysql-engine/) [two](http://dimitrik.free.fr/blog/archives/2012/11/mysql-performance-innodb-vs-myisam-in-56.html)[.](http://schimpf.es/myisam-and-innodb-compared/)

Comment: That's right. But i want to ask whether the  use of MyIsam affect join operation in Hibernate.

Comment: @Ritesh Even if you don't have foreign keys between two tables, you can still join them, the only thing you are loosing is data integrity.